# Mongo 3.4 in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is that possible to use Meteor with Mongo 3.4 for now? And if so, how to manage that?

I've tried to change `packages` file, but realised that version of `mongo` package is not a real Mongo's version.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible by taking care of mongodb yourself instead of letting meteor handle it. To do so you will have to fire up a mongod instance and set the MONGO_URL variable when you run meteor in development mode. In production mode you will be running a standalone mongodb instance anyway, so you will not need to change anything there.

As a reference, see this discussion on the meteor forums: https://forums.meteor.com/t/running-mongodb-3-4-locally-with-meteor/34242

To set an environment variable when running meteor in development mode requires the following:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor meteor
```

In this case you are accessing the meteor database (`/meteor`) on the local mongodb instance (`localhost`) on the standard port (`:27017`).

Comment: Could I use the CreateView function with 3.4 to make a view from an aggregate, and could I reference it like a read-only table in Meteor?